# Javascript reg ex need integer between 1 and 999999?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-plugins

I wish I could solve this by myself, but I have never quite grasped regular expressions.  They seem so powerful.  I wanted to ask where is the best resource to learn javascript reg ex, but that was to subjective and I didn't want my question closed.  I have a textbox on a web form, when it has a value, that value should be an integer between 1 & 999999.  I already use the jquery numeric plug in to only allow digits, all other keystrokes are rejected, there is an onBlur implementation, that if some regex is not matched, a callback will be called... This is that code...

```
$.fn.numeric.blur = function()
{
var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
var callback = $.data(this, "numeric.callback");
var val = $(this).val();
if(val != "")
{
    var re = new RegExp("^\\d+$|\\d*" + decimal + "\\d+");
    if(!re.exec(val))
    {
        callback.apply(this);
    }
}
}
```

Can I modify that regex to assure the val is a valid integer between 1 and 999999?  Any help would be appreciated.  Also obviously I would like to do this by myself, whats an easy way to learn javascript regex?  Thank you all so much.  Have a terrific holiday all!

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Is really a regular expression the right tool for validating integers?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot do a `>` or `<` comparison and Check if ROUND () equals the unrounded value?

Comment: @Raj More made a very sensible suggestion. (Why use a regular expression when there's really no need.) :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, I would recommend not to use a regular expression. Just use plain good old Javascript:

```
if( typeof decimal === 'number' && (decimal > 1 && decimal < 999999) ) {
     // here we go
}
```

To cast a value into a number, you can either use the `+` operator or `.parseInt()`

```
var val = +$.trim($(this).val());
if( val && (decimal >= 1 && decimal <= 999999) ) {
}
```

Comment: (decimal >= 1 && decimal <= 999999) ? :-)

Comment: OP said "between 1 and 999999" :)

Comment: +1 for advocating a non-regex solution. Although I would also `parseInt` or some other cast as `number` can represent more than just integer values.

Comment: True, he didn't say "inclusive". (I blame the spec.) Of course, what he *meant* to say was... :-)

Comment: This wouldn't really help, would it? It wouldn't work if decimal is "12345". I think the question is asking if the input is "12345" not if the value is 12345.

Answer (score 7):

This would do the job:

```
[0-9]{1,6}
```

I would suggest using an integer parsing/validation function instead though.

Comment: But this will match `0`, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a regex problem.  Have a look at the JQuery [.validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) function.  You can set the field requirements to range.

Answer (score 2):

```
var re = new RegExp("[1-9][0-9]{0,5}");
```

Should do it, and the best resource for regular expressions is probably http://www.regular-expressions.info/